# Sitecore ECM - Change Target Audience Opt In Role

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-ecm

Does anyone know how to update a Sitecore Target Audience Opt in role, via code? I want to change this based on a condition. I have tried:

> audience.OptInList.InnerRole = myRole;

But the InnerRole is readonly. I had a look through the developer docs at SDN but couldn't find a way to do this. Is there something I am missing? Does anyone know how to set this?

EDIT: 
I am using Sitecore 6.5 with rev 121009 ECM 1.3.2

Comment: What ECM version do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
audience.OptInList = ContactList.FromName(yourRoleName);
```

It replaces opt-in role of the Target Audience item.